# Api docs for docusign transaction rooms ?

Tags: docusignapi

For esign the api docs are available in https://docs.docusign.com/esign/. What is the equivalent for transaction rooms ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not have dedicated API docs for DocuSign Transaction Rooms (DTR). DocuSign have a restricted swagger for APIs but you cannot test the APIs without having your company created in DocuSign by a DocuSign Technical person. So I would recommend you to contact your DocuSign Account Manager who will help you in setting up DTR for development/testing, once a company is created for you then you can explore DTR APIs with the help of DTR Tech resource.